# Trying to compare values of a checkbox list with values of an array list c# with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, arrays, checkbox

We are currently programming a student information system. What we have so far is a checkboxlist that contains all the modules for the course that the selected student is enrolled on. These values are both stored in the database. What we are trying to do is have the List item values within the checkboxlist selected/ticked based upon the modules they are currently studying, based on what is stored in the database.

Here is our c# code:

```
    string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    myConnection.Open();

    string com5 = "SELECT ModuleID FROM StudentModules WHERE StudentID = @StudentID";
    SqlCommand myCommand5 = new SqlCommand(com5, myConnection);
    StudentIDLabel.Text = SearchText.Text;
    int StudentIDint = Convert.ToInt32(StudentIDLabel.Text);
    myCommand5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", StudentIDint);
    string compareModules = myCommand5.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


    var listOfStrings = new List<string>();

    SqlDataReader reader = myCommand5.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        String currentValue = reader.ToString();
        listOfStrings.Add(currentValue);
    }

    string[] arrayOfStrings = listOfStrings.ToArray();

    foreach (ListItem li in this.CbOptional.Items)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < arrayOfStrings.Length; x++)
        {
            if (li.Value.ToString() == arrayOfStrings[x])
            {
                li.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                li.Selected = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

From what we can see there seems to be an issue with IF statement, when comparing values from the checkbox list with values from the array.

We tested the else clause near the bottom of the above code, with "li.Selected = true" to make sure the code was running through the foreach statement correctly. All items within the checkbox list displayed as ticked. So this leads us to believe there is definitely something wrong with the IF statement inside the FOR loop.

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: DO You need to simply check the items of CHECKBOX(CbOptional) which are in LIST<listOfStrings> ?

Comment: effectively yes, and then if they match, display them as ticked on output.

Comment: i already posted the code which is working fine at my end, just check one thing more if the case is sensitive use .Tolower() at both the sides.

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, you are comparing the value of `ListItem` variable with each element in the array. Therefore, if the first element matches, the value is overwritten by the value of comparison with second element, and so on. Instead, you could try to check if the value of that particular `ListItem` matches any value in the list of strings retrieved from DB. You can do this like so:

```
if(listOfStrings.Contains(li.Value.ToString()))
 {
  li.Selected = true;
 }
```

Note that you do not need to convert the `listOfStrings` variable to an array, the `Contains` method works on `Lists`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in a reply above, when I change the else clause from false to true for test purposes then it works. This means i'm really close but just can't quite crack it!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to run two for loops. You can just iterate through array and check if there is list item which is having same value as array element on specific index.

Try this.

```
        for (int x = 0; x < arrayOfStrings.Length; x++)
        {
           ListItem listItemtoSelect = this.CbOptional.Items.FindByValue(arrayOfStrings[x]);

           if (listItemtoSelect != null)
             {
              listItemtoSelect.Selected = true;

             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `List<string>` will compare with the text only not value you should use this

> repace li.Value with li.Text

```
  for (int x = 0; x < arrayOfStrings.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (li.Text.ToString() == arrayOfStrings[x])
                    {
                        li.Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        li.Selected = false;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, however this still doesn't seem to have done the trick. I think there is a problem with the IF statement. Having changed the else clause to 'li.Selected = true' just to test, it then has the desired output and ticks all the boxes.

Comment: I tested this if else in my test project and posted here. Try debugging it, you ll surely solve it